# Stage one doesn't allow stage two to send mail if an item is edited

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, email

I have a workflow in which I have two stages. In stage 1: if status is uat it sends an email to user and sets column value (uatreminder) to yes.

In the second stage I have: if status is completed or rejected send email to user and set an column (emailsent) to yes.

But when I change the status to uat it sends an email to user regarding it but also shows that the workflow has gone to stage two. So when I edit the item to completed or rejected the user does not get email regarding it.

Can someone help me out as I cannot find the required solution to this.

[image]

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the workflow will be triggered automatically when an item is changed.
 [image]

The actions in Stage 1 will not affect actions in Stage 2 sine there are not conflicts between them.

Based on your workflow actions:

The workflow will check whether the “UAT Reminder” equals “UAT”, “Completed” or “Rejected” and then send email based on the result.

When you change “UAT Reminder” to UAT, the workflow will start and run the actions within it. First, it will check whether “UAT Reminder” equals “UAT”. Then, it will go to Stage 2, check if the “UAT Reminder” equals “Completed”/”Rejected”.

It is the correct situation.

You can check the workflow status by clicking the link. The Internal Status of the workflow should be "Completed". It means the workflow is finished successfully.

[image]

When you edit the item and change “UAT Reminder” to “Completed/Rejected” (or other values), a new workflow will be started and these actions will be run again to check “UAT Reminder” value if the workflow will be triggered automatically when an item is changed.

Comment: i appreciate your idea but i already figured the answer out to this solution.
But now i am dealing with a different problem in a new workflow.
i would be posting the question now.
hope you can help !
Thanks